# Line numbers misaligned using Prism code highlighter

Tags: javascript, html, css, highlight, prism.js

I'm using the [prism](http://prismjs.com/) library to highlight some HTML, CSS and JavaScript code. It does an amazing job for the most part, except when it comes to line numbers.

They look like:

[image: Misaligned line numbers]

As you can see, they are misaligned.
How can I fix this?
My current code looks like:

```
<div id="html-display" class="display code-display">
        <button class="explain-code">Explain this code</button>
        <span class="current-code"><pre class="line-numbers"><code class="language-markup">
&lt;!DOCTYPE html&gt;
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
    &lt;title&gt;a&lt;/title&gt;
    &lt;meta charset=&quot;UTF-8&quot;&gt;
    &lt;meta name=&quot;author&quot; content=&quot;A A&quot;&gt;
    &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; type=&quot;text/css&quot; href=&quot;design.css&quot;&gt;
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;jquery.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
    &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot; src=&quot;script.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;
&lt;body&gt;
    &lt;h1&gt;Test&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;/body&gt;
&lt;/html&gt;</code></pre></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same problem, had to hardcode (i.e. define in px, not relative) `code[class*="language-"]`s and `.line-numbers-rows > span:before`s `text-height` property in `prism.css` (with theme Twilight, Okaidia seems to work).

Comment: text-height? Do you mean line-height?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue. Fixed it by modifying .line-numbers-rows > span selector.

```
.line-numbers-rows > span {
  display: block;
  counter-increment: linenumber;
  line-height: 1.2rem; // add this
}
```